# Rewrtie some code from jQuery to JS (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Having an issue with the following piece of jQuery code. This is a small part of onSubmit event.

The exact trouble is that **:visible** selector. I'm in doubt on how to represent it correctly with the current (js+react) stack.

```
$( "form input:visible" ).each( function() {
 if (!$(this).val()){
  $(this).addClass( 'has-error' )
 }
} )
```

Input parents are hiding by CSS. 
The form won't be valid if any of them will have 'has-error' class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to approach this. One way is to store a piece of state, e.g. called `submitted`, and if `submitted` is `true`, then you can add the class `has-error` to all inputs in your render method that has an empty string as value and are visible.

**Example**

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  state = { email: "", username: "", submitted: false };
  changeEmail = e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  changeUsername = e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { email, username, submitted } = this.state;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          className={submitted && email.length === 0 ? "has-error" : ""}
          value={email}
          onChange={this.changeEmail}
        />
        <input
          className={submitted && username.length === 0 ? "has-error" : ""}
          value={username}
          onChange={this.changeUsername}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.has-error {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thak you a lot